# A question about Holder exponents of a function at different points in its domain

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that $f(x)$ is continuous on $[0,1]$. We make an agreement that if there exists an interval $[a,b]\subseteq[0,1]$ including point $y$ such that $f(x)$ satisfies $\alpha$-Holder condition on $[a,b]$, $f(x)$ satisfies $\alpha$-Holder condition at $y$. Define
$$A(y)=\sup\{\alpha : f(x) \text{ satisfies $\alpha$-Holder condition at $y$}\}.$$
What will the graph of $A(y)$ look like on $[0,1]$ for various $f(x)$, for example for functions of unbounded variation? Are there some constraints for $A(y)$?